# Proper method to Iterate and Load Images and title from Array (image_url) into ViewController in Swift

Tags: swift, swift4, uicollectionviewcell, swifty-json

I using a CollectionView with an ImageView in the prototype cell. I retrieve API result (title and image_url) and I would like to display an image and title in the collection view through array to retrieve the title and image_url.

Is it possible to retrieve image_url and display the image in the CollectionView?

I used SwiftyJSON to create the array and I can retrieve the API result (included title and image_url) in the array (can pint out the result). But I can't show it in the collection view.

Comment: Can you show a [mcve]?

Answer (score 0):

**I am posting an example code for your problem that might help you.**

// Array that you retrieve from your API

```
let titleAndImageArray = []()
```

//CollectionView DataSourceMethod

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return titleAndImageArray.count
}



func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
 let cell:YourCollectionViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! YourCollectionViewCell
 let labelTitle = titleAndImageArray[indexPath.row].title
 let musicImageUrlString = titleAndImageArray[indexPath.row].image_url
 cell.yourLabelOutletName.text = labelTitle
 loadImage(indexPath: indexPath, cell: cell, urlString:musicImageUrlString)
    }
```

*I have created a loadImage function to get image from URL which uses SDWebImage library which is Asynchronous image downloader [SDWebImage](https://github.com/SDWebImage/SDWebImage) *

```
  func loadImage(indexPath:IndexPath,cell:YourCollectionViewCell,urlString:String){
    cell.yourImageViewOutletName.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: urlString), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "App-Default"),options: SDWebImageOptions(rawValue: 0), completed: { (image, error, cacheType, imageURL) in

    })
}
```

Comment: func fetchFoodList(){
let url = URL(string: "https://MYAPIKey&q=chicken%20breast&page=2")
guard let unwrappedUrl = url else { return }
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: unwrappedUrl, completionHandler: {(data, response, error)in if error != nil{
print(error!)} else { if let urlContent = data{
do {
let json = try JSON(data:data!)
let recipes = json["recipes"] print(recipes)
for arr in recipes.arrayValue{ print(arr["title"])
print(arr["image_url"])
}}
catch{ print("JSON Processing Failed")}}}
})task.resume()

Comment: Your code seems correct. You can store the title and image_url in the array and then use the array as a data model for collection view data source methods.

Comment: But it still can't display an image and title in the collection view